# How can I print document wise topics in Gensim?

Tags: python, nltk, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I'm using LDA with gensim for topic modeling. My data has 23 documents and I want separate topics/words for each document but gensim is giving topics for entire set of documents together. How to get it for  individual docs?

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(doc_clean)

# Converting list of documents (corpus) into Document Term Matrix using 
#dictionary prepared above.

corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in doc_clean]


# Creating the object for LDA model using gensim library
Lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel

# Running and Trainign LDA model on the document term matrix.
ldamodel = Lda(corpus, num_topics=3, id2word = dictionary, passes=50)

result=ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=3, num_words=3)
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
[(0, '0.011*"plex" + 0.010*"game" + 0.009*"racing"'),
(1, '0.008*"app" + 0.008*"live" + 0.007*"share"'),
(2, '0.015*"device" + 0.009*"file" + 0.008*"movie"')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print_topics()` returns a list of topics, the words loading onto that topic and those words.

If you want the topic loadings per document, instead, you need to use `get_document_topics()`.

From the [gensim documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html):

---

`get_document_topics(bow, minimum_probability=None, minimum_phi_value=None, per_word_topics=False)`

Get the topic distribution for the given document.

**Parameters:** 
`bow (corpus : list of (int, float))` – The document in BOW format.
`minimum_probability (float)` – Topics with an assigned probability lower than this threshold will be discarded.
`minimum_phi_value (float)` – If `per_word_topics` is `True`, this represents a lower bound on the term probabilities that are included.
If set to `None`, a value of `1e-8` is used to prevent 0s.
`per_word_topics (bool)` – If `True`, this function will also return two extra lists as explained in the “Returns” section.

**Returns:**
`list of (int, float)` – Topic distribution for the whole document. Each element in the list is a pair of a topic’s id, and the probability that was assigned to it.

`list of (int, list of (int, float)`, optional – Most probable topics per word. Each element in the list is a pair of a word’s id, and a list of topics sorted by their relevance to this word. Only returned if `per_word_topics` was set to `True`.

`list of (int, list of float)`, optional – `Phi` relevance values, multiplied by the feature length, for each word-topic combination. Each element in the list is a pair of a word’s id and a list of the phi values between this word and each topic. Only returned if `per_word_topics` was set to `True`.

---

`get_term_topics()` and `get_topic_terms()` may also be potentially interesting for you.

Comment: get_document_topics() returns list of probability distributions only, what I want is name of words or topics per document.

Comment: Please clarify - the topics in topic modeling dont have names, so I am still uncertain as to what you want. Can you add the "desired output" to your question?

Comment: In the output I posted, it is showing some words/names along with their prob distributions but it is for all the documents combined, I want that thing for each individual doc, is it possible?

Comment: I still think you may want `get_document_topics()` - it returns a list of all the topics and the extent to which each document loads onto that topic. The topics do not have "names" - these you would have to come up with yourself - but are numbered. So document 1 may have a loading on topic 1 of 0.4, a loading on topic 2 of 0.3, etc...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to put the entire thing inside a loop and do `print_topics()`:

Your documents example:

```
doc1 = "Brocolli is good to eat. My brother likes to eat good brocolli, but not my mother."
doc2 = "My mother spends a lot of time driving my brother around to baseball practice."
doc3 = "Some health experts suggest that driving may cause increased tension and blood pressure."
doc_set = [doc_a, doc_b, doc_c]
```

Now your loop must iterate through your `doc_set`:

```
for i in doc_set:
      ##### after all the cleaning in these steps, append to a list #####

      dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(doc_clean)
      corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in doc_clean]

      ##### set the num_topics you want for each document, I set one for now #####

      ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics = 1, id2word = dictionary, passes=20)
      for i in ldamodel.print_topics():
          print(i)
          print('\n')
```

Sample output:

```
(0, '0.200*"brocolli" + 0.200*"eat" + 0.200*"good" + 0.133*"brother" + 0.133*"like" + 0.133*"mother"')


(0, '0.097*"brocolli" + 0.097*"eat" + 0.097*"good" + 0.097*"mother" + 0.097*"brother" + 0.065*"lot" + 0.065*"spend" + 0.065*"practic" + 0.065*"around" + 0.065*"basebal"')


(0, '0.060*"drive" + 0.060*"eat" + 0.060*"good" + 0.060*"mother" + 0.060*"brocolli" + 0.060*"brother" + 0.040*"pressur" + 0.040*"health" + 0.040*"caus" + 0.040*"increas"')
```

Comment: I tried your approach but it is giving same output as before, using loop didn't made any difference